# How to capture slider events in Foundation 4 Orbit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I want my page to change some elements with each slide in the slider. I managed to do this in the desktop version, by attaching functions to the click events, like this:

```
$(".orbit-next").on("click", nextChange);
$(".orbit-prev").on("click", prevChange);
```

But that doesn't work in the touch slide version :(
Does anyone know how to achieve this? I couldn't find any event related to the touch slide, neither any function to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in the 'foundation.orbit.js', you can see the events that it uses.

```
'orbit:after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit'
'orbit:next-slide.fndtn.orbit click.fndtn.orbit'
'orbit:prev-slide.fndtn.orbit click.fndtn.orbit'
'orbit:toggle-play-pause.fndtn.orbit click.fndtn.orbit touchstart.fndtn.orbit' 
'touchstart.fndtn.orbit'
'touchmove.fndtn.orbit'
'touchend.fndtn.orbit'
```

You can listen to these using jQuery [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) on the element used by orbit.

```
$("[data-orbit]").bind('orbit:after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit', function(event){
      console.log('slide change', event);
      //alert('slide change', event);

      //do clever stuff
    });
```

The 'after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit' is probably most useful as this should fire on all devices. (I tested this in Chrome and on the iPad).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had to remove `orbit:` before `after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit` in order to get it to work.  Maybe new syntax: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/foundation/foundation.orbit.js#L119.